# UINavigationItem lifecycle

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

As far as I understand the SDK documentation UIViewController's navigationItem lifecycle is bound to the controller itself and not to the controller's view. I.e. in the default implementation it is created on-demand and destroyed with the view controller - with all contents like button items and titleView. Given that both button items and the titleView may be represented by UIView instances - does that mean that once created these views will stay in memory until controller is destroyed and live through all memory warnings?

What is the sense behind this design decision? Is impact for memory usage considered too small to bother? Is it really small for an application which is using customized nav bar buttons/titles everywhere?

It is easy to explicitly bound some of the navigationItem properties to the controller's view lifecycle - like setting titleView in -viewDidLoad and dropping it in -viewDidUnload (`self.navigationItem.titleView = nil`). But the navigationItem property documentation [suggests to avoid this pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationItem). Are there any other potential problems other than the given example with back button?

Answer (score 0):

Added a category (snippet2) to track the retain count and the destruction of the navigation items, feel free to do the same :) Seems like it is not deallocated with the memory warning. An explanation would come from a common sense that view controllers don't have to be used with the navigation controller: that should be why the nav-item is added with a separate category (snippet1) and it's lifecycle must be managed with a nav-controller, not the view controller instance itself.

In the case the custom nav-items are so heavy that you need to release it whenever possible, 
 i would leave the default implementation, add custom nav-items category and manage this items manually as i wish (again through overriding required `UINavigationController` methods like nav-controllers `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, `pushViewController:animated:`, `popViewControllerAnimated:animated:`). I can't imagine such a case when it is really needed however.

snippet 1

```
@interface UIViewController (UINavigationControllerItem)

@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UINavigationItem *navigationItem; // Created on-demand so that a view controller may customize its navigation appearance.
@property(nonatomic) BOOL hidesBottomBarWhenPushed; // If YES, then when this view controller is pushed into a controller hierarchy with a bottom bar (like a tab bar), the bottom bar will slide out. Default is NO.
@property(nonatomic,readonly,retain) UINavigationController *navigationController; // If this view controller has been pushed onto a navigation controller, return it.

@end
```

snippet 2

```
@implementation UINavigationItem (Logs)


- (id)init
{
    NSLog(@"I'm initialized (%@)", [self description]);
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

-(void) release
{
    NSLog(@"I'm released [%d](%@)", [self retainCount], [self description]);
    [super release];
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"I'm deallocated [%d](%@)", [self retainCount], [self description]);
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Tracking the retain count is useless. Just track the dealloc.

Comment: @bbum i was impressed by a large release calls count, not sure someone else finds it interesting, but whatever. Release call with the retainCount 1 should be just fine as the log is placed before `[super release]`. I dunno whether the dealloc `must` be called `immediately` after such a release, but that is pretty close to dealloc for me.

Comment: I think you misunderstood;  the result returned from `retainCount` is meaningless, both in this context and in general, and the override of `release` doesn't show anything particularly interesting.  While you could set a breakpoint there, you are far better off using the Allocations instrument to track all retain/release events.

Comment: @bbum i can't agree the `retainCount` is meaningless and i seriously doubt setting the breakpoint at release is better then log it. I also had many problems using the Instruments so i prefer to use a stable solution which also provides us the chance for an ad-hoc testing. Cheers.

Comment: There is nothing that retainCount can tell you that can't be better found through other means.  That combined with how grossly misleading it is (see http://whentouseretaincount.com) makes it useless.   I didn't mean to imply that setting a breakpoint on release was an alternative, but that debugging by logging, say, release without context of backtrace is next to useless, as well.  You might find success through these patterns, but that doesn't mean there aren't much **much** better ways of doing it.

Comment: @bbum Looked at the link, your concern is clear, i will highly appreciate if you read again the "For example...You'd think that" section and understand, that not everyone would think this way, some programmers do have a good algorithmic understanding :) Some can not find anything misleading in `retainCount` behavior mentioned there. Let's be honest, it's only a  scaring-kids tale, not the professional manifest. As for the log - it's a one among others tool we are using at convenience (hey, i'm not saying `NSLog` should be used to collect a trace, but improved version might be very powerful).

Comment: It very much is the professional manifest;   the only reason why retainCount isn't deprecated and removed is due to legacy compatibility issues.  In fact, it is removed in ARC exactly because ARC was able to break that constraint.  If you understand the algorithms behind `retainCount` -- that it never reflects autorelease, is useless in the face of the threads, and is often seemingly random for framework provided classes -- you would know that it is useless for debugging (especially in light of the many better tools available).

Comment: @bbum No, I still can't understand what's the problem with that behavior. The same property, disappearing in every pending autorelease, divided into threads and reflecting only the user created ownerships (sic) would be a useless piece of rainbow, while with all the things you mentioned are natural. That's about knowing the weak points and easily considering it. As far as i know, `retainCount` is not deprecated, neither removed, there's no need to switch to ARC in the near feature, i'm also not aware of any compatibility issue other then a low knowledge level of the newcomers.

Comment: @A-Live - A word of advice: you may wish to check where he works, and the projects he's had a hand in, before continuing this argument. You're not going to win this. Also, you should probably read his epic teardown of `-retainCount`, which will hopefully clarify things: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/

Comment: @Brad Larson @bbum The article is great as the description and i particularly like the "So, when is retainCount useful" concluding section. However - might you go back to the ground for a few minutes and have a look on the question from there ? You have 8 clarification points there, that's great. Why are you trying to persuade us to forget the `retainCount` rather then understand the concept and use it in the appropriate way ? That's a mystery unsolved for me, probably communicating with the less experienced crowd you have to do it for other's sake, thank you then.